# How can I set a bean name when implements AsyncConfigurer#getAsyncExecutor()

Tags: spring

I tried like this

```
    @Bean(name = AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {

        final ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setCorePoolSize(1);
        factoryBean.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        factoryBean.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        factoryBean.setBeanName(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME);
        factoryBean.setKeepAliveSeconds(10);
        factoryBean.setQueueCapacity(100);
        factoryBean.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(30);
        factoryBean.setThreadNamePrefix("spring-mvc--");

        return factoryBean.getObject();
        // return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }
```

but I got this Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'taskExecutor' is expected to be of type 'java.util.concurrent.Executor' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'
```

How can I set a bean name when implements AsyncConfigurer#getAsyncExecutor() ?

Comment: You don't as `getAsyncExecutor` isn't an `@Bean` method. What you should do is create an `@Bean` method that creates the bean and call that method from `getAsyncExecutor`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason.

I should call `factoryBean.initialize();` before `return factoryBean.getObject();`, or else  `factoryBean.getObject()` will return null;

Comment: You should have created a seperate `@BEan` method that returns the `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` so that Spring will do all that for you. Those are basically Spring lifecycle methods.